# Langchain 'terminal' issue with "nano"

Tags: langchain

I have installed nano using chocolatey but whenever I'am creating an agent that is supposed to use the terminal to modify a script, it run for an infinite time.

Here is the script :

```
import os
from langchain.agents import load_tools, initialize_agent, Tool 
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.agents import tool 

OPENAI_KEY = os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
Tools = []
tools = load_tools(['terminal'],llm=llm)


agent = initialize_agent(tools, llm, agent='zero-shot-react-description', verbose=True)
agent.run("Create a simple text file. after it's created, use nano to add a 'I AM HERE' inside of it.")
```

the result is the following:
←[1m> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...←[0m
←[32;1m←[1;3m I need to create a file and then open it in nano.
Action: Terminal
Action Input: touch text.txt && nano text.txt←[0m

Any ideas?

I'am sure it's not about nano function since I can do all steps manually.